# Creating new instance of class using template, don't know how to handle error

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, binary-search-tree, dereference

I'll try and keep the code short.

I'm trying to make a **B** inary **S** earch **T** ree (BST for short) using templates.

In my add function I'm getting an error and I'm sure I'm misusing templates somehow

All this code is in a .h (header) file because of templates.

**EDIT:** The const Type & mistake was because of me fiddling around, it was not actually in the code I compile, but from a previous question on Stack overflow

```
template <typename Type>
class BSTNode {   // Binary Search Tree nodes
  private:
    int key;      // we search by key, no matter what type of data we have
    Type data;
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;

  public:
    BSTNode (int, Type);     // key, data
    bool add (int, Type);
};
```

The add function:

```
template <typename Type>
bool BSTNode<Type>::add(int newKey, Type newData) {
  if (newKey < this->key) {
    if (left == NULL) {
      this->left = new BSTNode<Type>(int newKey, Type newData);
    }
  } else {
    this->right = new BSTNode<Type>(int newKey, Type newData);
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is where I get the error:

```
this->left = new BSTNode<Type>(int newKey, Type newData);
```

Expected primary expression before int

Comment: We already know what BST stands for. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not misuing templates specifically, but you are misusing parameters!

```
this->left = new BSTNode<Type>(int newKey, Type newData);
```

should look more like

```
this->left = new BSTNode<Type>(newKey, newData);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Don't know how I missed that, but I was looking over the code for half an hour now, got tunnel-vision'ed.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `this->left = new BSTNode<Type>(newKey, newData);` without any types.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear:

```
 bool add (int, Type);
```

vs

```
 bool add(int newKey, const Type &newData)
```

You should change your declaration in the class definition to:

```
 bool add (int, const Type&);
```

and remove the types from the statements:

```
 this->right = new BSTNode<Type>(int newKey, Type newData);
 this->right = new BSTNode<Type>(int newKey, Type newData);
```

should be

```
 this->right = new BSTNode<Type>(newKey, newData);
 this->right = new BSTNode<Type>(newKey, newData);
```

Comment: Ok, solved now, don't know how I missed it, guess I'll go with blaming tunnel vision